# Weird input bug on c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, input, xna-4.0

Errm...Let's see...The bug my project is having is...Weird.
I'm making a Monster Training game,and when it enters on the battle mode,there is a bug that may happen,once you press the key to the left or the right of the controls,before you enter on the battle.
The bug is simple,for example,if you press A(Aka left button),when it lets you choose the action you will take,the game keeps recognizing as if the A button is still pressed,even if it isn't.
This is the code that is causing the bug:

```
    public static int ChooseAction()
    {
        int choosen = 0;
        Battle.CanAct = true;
        Battle.ChoosenAction = -1;
        while (Battle.ChoosenAction == -1)
        {
            if (Battle.KeyDelay == 0)
            {
                if (Procedures.ButtonPressed(Procedures.KeyCodes.KeyRight))
                {
                    Battle.KeyDelay = 64;
                    int a = Battle.SelectedAction;
                    a++;
                    if (a >= BattleActions.Length)
                    {
                        a -= BattleActions.Length;
                    }
                    Battle.SelectedAction = a;
                }
                else if (Procedures.ButtonPressed(Procedures.KeyCodes.KeyLeft))
                {
                    Battle.KeyDelay = 64;
                    int a = Battle.SelectedAction;
                    a--;
                    if (a < 0)
                    {
                        a += BattleActions.Length;
                    }
                    Battle.SelectedAction = a;
                }
                else if (Procedures.ButtonPressed(Procedures.KeyCodes.Action))
                {
                    Battle.ChoosenAction = Battle.SelectedAction;
                }
            }
            if (KeyDelay != 0 && !Procedures.ButtonPressed(Procedures.KeyCodes.KeyRight) && !Procedures.ButtonPressed(Procedures.KeyCodes.KeyLeft))
            {
                KeyDelay = 0;
            }
            if (Battle.KeyDelay > 0)
            {
                Battle.KeyDelay--;
            }
        }
        choosen = Battle.ChoosenAction;
        Battle.CanAct = false;
        return choosen;
    }
```

I don't know if this will help,but that script runs on a thread,since it's maden based on the modification of the official script,that were in c# console.
Also,the ButtonPress procedure,returns if the button is pressed,but it ever creates a new boolean everytime it is called.
Any clue of what may be causing the bug?
The Procedures.ButtonPress(KeyCodes) script.

```
public static bool ButtonPressed(KeyCodes buttonKey)
{
    bool pressed = false;

    switch (buttonKey)
    {
        case KeyCodes.MenuKey:
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.M) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Buttons.Start))
                pressed = true;
            break;

        case KeyCodes.RunKey:
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.LeftShift) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.RightShift) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Buttons.B))
                pressed = true;
            break;

        case KeyCodes.KeyUp:
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.W) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Up) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Buttons.DPadUp))
                pressed = true;
            break;

        case KeyCodes.KeyDown:
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.S) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Down) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Buttons.DPadDown))
                pressed = true;
            break;

        case KeyCodes.KeyLeft:
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.A) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Left) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Buttons.DPadLeft))
                pressed = true;
            break;

        case KeyCodes.KeyRight:
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.D) || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Right) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Buttons.DPadRight))
                pressed = true;
            break;

        case KeyCodes.Action:
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Enter) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Buttons.A))
                pressed = true;
            break;

        case KeyCodes.Return:
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Escape) || GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsButtonDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Buttons.B))
                pressed = true;
            break;
    }
    return pressed;
}
```

Comment: How about instead of a press you take advantage of button up/down events ?
Once button was let go - get out of the loop.

Comment: I don't think it whould work,also,the players will find it very annoying,pressing up or down button to debug it,if do that is the solution,but certainly isn't...Also,your suggestion didn't worked.

Comment: Can we get the code of Procedures.ButtonPressed? Maybe the bug is there. We could also change that method using another way to check for a keydown and see if that solves the issue

Comment: Sure,checkout main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading XNA and setting up everything (yes I'm bored at work), I tried the code on a simple menu and it works flawlessly.

The problem is that for some reason XNA's input is not threadable. It doesn't work at all for me when I create another thread with the input. I tried various keys and none of them get a pressed state but the letter "R" which once it's pressed, it stays that way.

I also tried with the R to save the original keyboard state and once the state changes use the original to compare if R was pressed and it worked. However, you will know just ONCE that R was pressed and you won't know if it's being pressed again.

After doing all that I googled and I found recommendations to ALWAYS check your input on your main thread on the update method (as I did at first)

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Wow,that was unexpected.By the way,i'll have to find a way of using a non threading way of checking the inputs.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well,bug fixed,on the drawing script,that isn't on a thread,i added the control scripts,the only problem now is that the fps is so extreme,that the menu is switching too fast,but this one i can handle,thanks for the help again.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help =). It was unexpected to me as well. You probably know this but you can limit specific things with the Gametime class. Check for the delta on Gametime and if it's too small you can ignore the input action.